# Multiplying raw_input variables

Tags: python

I'm getting stuck in multiplying variables.
For example...

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
float(hrs)
rateperhr = raw_input("Enter rate:")
float(rateperhr)
grosspay = (hrs) * (rateperhr)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 5, in <module>
    grosspay = (hrs) * (rateperhr)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you forgot to:

```
hrs = float(hrs)
```

and:

```
rateperhr = float(rateperhr)
```

No need for parentheses:

```
grosspay = hrs * rateperhr
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the value the float() function is returning. According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float, the float() function returns a floating-point number constructed from its input, and as such doesn't *directly* modify anything.

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
hrs = float(hrs)

rateperhr = raw_input("Enter rate:")
rateperhr = float(rateperhr)

grosspay = hrs * rateperhr
```

Answer (score 2):

It says: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
Because your are not assigning float type to variables. If you want to change variable type you have to write:

```
hrs = float(hrs)
```

Your code well written:

```
hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))
rateperhr = float(raw_input("Enter rate:"))
grosspay = (hrs) * (rateperhr)
print grosspay1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways for solving you problem. Apart from the answers mentioned above you can use 'input' instead of raw_input or make use of 'eval'.

```
>>> hrs = input("Enter hrs: ")
Enter hrs: 10
>>> type(hrs)
<type 'int'>

>>> hrs = input("Enter hrs: ")
Enter hrs: 10.0
>>> type(hrs)
<type 'float'>

# Using eval
 >>> hrs = eval(raw_input("Enter hrs: "))
 >>> type(hrs)
```